# Python converting a dataframe of string type list to list

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a unique situation. I get a data from the field in row format. Each row contains a timestamp, a list of values. It is in string format. I am trying to convert it to a normal list.

My code:

```
df=
     A
0    '1.2,1.3'
1    '2.2,2.3'   
2    '3.2,3.3,'
3    '4.2,4.3'
import ast
df['A'] = df['A'].applymap(ast.literal_eval).applymap(list)
```

Present output:

```
ValueError: malformed node or string: 
[3.2,3.3]
```

Expected output:

```
df=
     A
0    [1.2,1.3]
1    [2.2,2.3]   
2    [3.2,3.3]
3    [4.2,4.3]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```py
import ast

df["A"] = df["A"].apply(lambda x: ast.literal_eval("[" + x + "]"))
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
            A
0  [1.2, 1.3]
1  [2.2, 2.3]
2  [3.2, 3.3]
3  [4.2, 4.3]
```

---

If there are `'` in the strings:

```py
df["A"] = (
    df["A"].str.strip("'").apply(lambda x: ast.literal_eval("[" + x + "]"))
)
```

Comment: The first part gave error: `ValueError: malformed node or string: timestamp
2019-02-05 10:52:33` , second part gave error: `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'`

Comment: @Mainland Can you please update your question with real data? It seems, that the strings don't contain numbers in format xx.yy.

Comment: The data is so big. I presented here an example. How do I share the big data?

Comment: @Mainland It doesn't have to by big. Just the sample that produces the error.

Comment: Hi, I just framed a new question and this might help me solve the problem here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68745282/python-dataframe-saving-a-list-in-a-cell

Comment: What if the row has one more `,` at the end? I literally got an error. For instance, in the above example, `2    '3.2,3.3,,'` how to overcome this problem

Comment: @Mainland You can try to use `lambda x: ast.literal_eval("[" + x.strip(",") + "]")`

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
df["A"].str.replace("'", "").str.rstrip(",").str.split(",").apply(lambda x : list(map(lambda y : float(y), x)))
```

This cleans up the string for trailing commas and casts the values to floats.

Answer (score 0):

One option can be to use [`pandas.str.extractall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html) combined with [`pd.to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html):

```
df.apply(
     lambda s: s.str.extractall(r'(\d+(?:\.\d+))').values.ravel(),axis=1)
  .apply(pd.Series)
  .apply(pd.to_numeric)

     0    1
0  1.2  1.3
1  2.2  2.3
2  3.2  3.3
3  4.2  4.3
```